# How to exempt localhost from SMTP smart relay?

Tags: postfix, smtp, sasl

I've got a mail server (mail.mydomain.com) that has a relay set up as such:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**:

```
# Smarthost
relayhost = [smtpcorp.com]:2525
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/smtpcorp_passwd
```

So any of my users using `mail.mydomain.com` as their SMTP server will basically authenticate with their own username and password (the same they use for dovecot) and they get relayed to `smtpcorp.com` which has its own username/password they never see. This works great.

However, when `mail.mydomain.com` runs cron scripts and tries to email root, which is aliased to my email address, it fails because there's no authentication going on.

```
Jul 27 08:34:06 mail postfix/smtp[5058]: D37641FA98: to=<xxx@xxx.com>, relay=smtpcorp.com[207.58.147.66]:2525, delay=0.96, delays=0/0/0.86/0.1, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host smtpcorp.com[207.58.147.66] said: 550 Relay denied for unauthenticated sender (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

How can I exempt `localhost` and `mail.mydomain.com` from either:

1. Having to use the SMTP smart relay at all
2. Or simply not being required to use SASL authentication to use the smart relay

**/etc/aliases**:

```
mailer-daemon: postmaster
postmaster: root

root: me@xxx.com
```

If I remove the root alias, mail delivery works fine, but I want the alias there so that it will forward and get delivered so my regular mail client can access it via dovecot.

***Server info: Debian 7.5, postfix 2.9.6***

Output of `postconf -n`:

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
disable_vrfy_command = yes
enable_original_recipient = no
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s
maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d
minimal_backoff_time = 1000s
mydestination = mail.myvps.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = mail.myvps.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = /etc/hostname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_helo_timeout = 60s
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/smtpcorp_passwd
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_limit = 16
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/mail.myvps.com/ca-bundle
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/mail.myvps.com/crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/mail.myvps.com/key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/vimb/virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:8
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/vimb/virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/vimb/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:150
```

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. Only non-local mails are sent to `relayhost`. Since you are forwarding the mail to `me@xxx.com`, where `xxx.com` is non-local domain, `relayhost` is used for delivery. Why cant you setup authentication for `me@xxx.com` in your `smtp_sasl_password_maps`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. I don't know the format of the `smtp_sasl_password_maps` hash file. Right now it just contains the SMTP user/pass for my `smtpcorp.com` account. How do I add a specific destination (`me@xxx.com`) in there?

Comment: I guess I don't understand. If I try to use command line mail to send to, e.g., `steve@gmail.com`, it fails, saying I'm an unauthenticated sender. Even though the hash file is correct and contains the username/password for the `smtpcorp.com` relay.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude xxx@xxx.com to using relayhost by setting empty relay host in `transport_maps`

```
#main.cf
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport

#/etc/postfix/transport
xxx@xxx.com     smtp:
```